# Trigger to create contact based on opportunity data

Tags: apex, trigger

For weird and "before my time" reasons, we have some custom fields on our opportunity object to gather names and email addresses of people that are related to the opportunity. Now we have a requirement to automatically create contacts on the parent account of the opportunity based on these names and email addresses. I've been trying to write a trigger to accomplish this, but as my Apex skills are still developing, I'm stumped. Can anyone give me some direction on how to accomplish this?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Hi Matt, you said based on these names and email addresses in you explanation where you are refering to this names and addresses .

Answer (score 1):

There are many components to this question, but instead of closing it as too broad, I will enumerate some of the aspects that you should research more yourself, and provide some small amount of technical guidance to set you on the right track.

- Use a [handler pattern](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices) for your trigger
- You need to worry about deduplication, in other words how do you make sure you only create a Contact once? This will likely involve some querying.
- You need to worry about error handling. If an update to some `Opportunity` record causes creation of a `Contact` record that then throws an error, what do you do? There are a lot of ways to handle errors (even failing silently), but you need to determine which is/are appropriate.
- You need to do all this without torching your governor limits. Make sure to use the Aggregate-Query-Update pattern, building up your collection of records and then inserting them all at once. Also be sure to perform any queries on collections and not per record.

Aside from all that, this is a good use case for `Custom Settings`, specifically of the `List` type. That way you can configure groupings of fields (by `API Name`) that should correspond to a `Contact` record. Probably here I would use the email field you want as the `Name` on this setting (`Custom Setting` names are unique, though they are also limited to 80 characters so you may need a different field).

Custom Setting:

```
Opportunity_Contact__c
    Name - Text(80) (Email Field)
    First_Name_Field__c - Text(255)
    Last_Name_Field__c - Text(255)
    etc.
```

Then in your code, you would loop through each `Custom Setting` for each `Opportunity` and create your `Contact` records. You will also have to worry about deduplication (not creating the same record twice), but you should try to solve the problem and ask a more specific question if you struggle with that.

```
static List<Contact> buildContacts(Opportunity opportunity)
{
    List<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>();
    for (Opportunity_Contact__c mapping : Opportunity_Contact__c.getAll().values())
    {
        Contact contact = new Contact();
        contact.Email = opportunity.get(mapping.Name);
        contact.FirstName = opportunity.get(mapping.First_Name_Field__c);
        contact.LastName = opportunity.get(mapping.Last_Name_Field__c);
        contacts.add(contact)
    }
    return contacts;
}
```